# How to loop over a dataframe combining 5 columns per iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I need to combine 5 columns, then combine the next 5 columns and so on. As I am a beginner could you help me writing a loop or better solution using below's sample?

```
df[df.columns[24:29]].apply(lambda x: "".join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
df[df.columns[29:34]].apply(lambda x: "".join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
df[df.columns[34:39]].apply(lambda x: "".join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
```

EDIT:

All I need is a loop that takes 5 successive columns, do the above transformation and proceeds to the next 5 successive columns, hence [24:29], next [29:34] and so on.

Keep in mind that column headers are text.

Sample data:

```
{'Respondent': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9},
 'Statement1': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: 1.0,
  7: nan,
  8: nan},
 'unnamed25': {0: 2.0,
  1: nan,
  2: 2.0,
  3: 2.0,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: 2.0,
  8: nan},
 'unnamed26': {0: nan,
  1: 3.0,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: 3.0},
 'unnamed27': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: 4.0,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan},
 'unnamed28': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: 5.0,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan}}
```

Desired output:

```
{'Respondent': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9},
 'Statement1': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3}}
```

Comment: So let's say you have a DF of 40 columns... you'd want a new DF with 8 columns?

Comment: That's right. It needs to combine 5 successive columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original question

You could try something like this. For a `DataFrame` like;

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(30, size=[5, 20]))
```

Which looks like

```
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   12  15  21  0   3   27  3   7   9   19
1   21  18  4   23  6   24  24  12  26  1
2   6   7   23  14  24  17  5   25  13  8
3   9   20  19  16  19  5   15  15  0   18
4   3   24  17  19  29  19  19  14  7   0
```

Then you can apply the following

```
# Transpose the dataframe and create "n" groups (in your case 5) in your index.
df_t = df.T
df_t.index = df_t.index // 5

# We can now do something to each of these groups. Here we can 
# concatenate the string using `sum` and setting `numeric_only=False` after converting to str. 
# We can then transpose back to get the required result
df_t.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).sum(numeric_only=False)).T
```

which outputs

```
           0            1
0   12152103    2737919
1   21184236    242412261
2   67231424    17525138
3   920191619   51515018
4   324171929   19191470
```

---

## Edited question

Based on your new requirements, to drop null values in batches of 5's and take the only integers in those groups, you can try.

```
statements = df.iloc[:, 1:]

# repeat the same procedure here
df_t = statements.T.reset_index(drop=True)
df_t.index = df_t.index // 5

# This time, for each group, use `fillna` and take the first column of each group
new_statements = df_t.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='backfill').iloc[0]).T

# Then rejoin with the original dataframe
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, 0], new_statements], axis=1)


# df
   Respondent     0
0           1   2.0
1           2   3.0
2           3   2.0
3           4   2.0
4           5   4.0
5           6   5.0
6           7   1.0
7           8   2.0
8           9   3.0
```

You can name your columns accordingly.

Comment: Can you include what an example of your input and output please?

Comment: Just did. For statement 1, I need one column named "Statement1" and gives the chosen digit. There can only be 1 digit as you can see from the sample data

Comment: And what should your output look like given this input? I'm struggling to visualise what you're output from your original post to now

Comment: I've added it to the post

Comment: I will have a look at this tomorrow for you

Comment: is there guaranteed to be only one value in each row per group, like in your example? Will these be of type `str` or `int` or `float`?

Comment: Yes only 1 value, int

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10,40)))
pd.DataFrame([df[df.columns[i:i+5]].apply(
     lambda x: " ".join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1) for i in range(0,df.shape[1],5)]).T
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for effort. Please read my edit above. Column headers are text